# Swift - Update and store position of a multiple programmatically created buttons

Tags: arrays, swift, button, plist, programmatically-created

I have a button which creates other buttons based on the class Clip seen below. Those newly created buttons are added to an array and stored in a plist.

```
class Clip: Encodable, Decodable {
var name: String = ""
var xCoordinate: Int = 100
var yCoordinate: Int = 300
// more parameter will be added later on e.g color, scale etc..
}
```

Each button can be moved around the view and the new x & y coordinates are stored in a plist.

```
@objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    let uIViewSelected = sender.view!

    switch sender.state {
    case .began, .changed :
        moveViewWithPan(view: uIViewSelected, sender: sender)
        break
    case .ended:
      //Finds the position when the button is no longer being dragged

        let x = Int(uIViewSelected.center.x)
        let y = Int(uIViewSelected.center.y)

      //clipArray[0] need to be the corresponding clicked button e.g clipArray[2]

        clipArray[0].xCoordinate = x
        clipArray[0].yCoordinate = y
        saveData()
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

The above works only if I create one button. When more buttons are added, the above lines only change the first clip from the array. I need a way to update the value to the correct button clicked.

How can identify the array position of the click button as I am creating all them programmatically? At the moment I am placing at value 0 of the clipArray.

```
 clipArray[0].xCoordinate = x
 clipArray[0].yCoordinate = y
```

I am not even sure if using a plist is the best way to store the buttons in the first place.

Any help or documentation would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but have you considered using the `tag` property that any `UIView` has?

Comment: Thanks dfd, that could work from the look of it. I will try it later.

Comment: Dfd thanks it does work at the moment. I need to do further testing though. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following from dfd response, I added tags to each button which are created and it solved the issue for now.

```
        let x = Int(uIViewSelected.center.x)
        let y = Int(uIViewSelected.center.y)
        //clipArray.append(clip)

        var tagNo = uIViewSelected.tag

        clipArray[tagNo].xCoordinate = x
        clipArray[tagNo].yCoordinate = y
```